# How to add Samba user "nobody" with pdbedit?

Tags: samba, samba4

How do I add the Samba user `nobody` (for public shares) with `pdbedit`?

The old style would be `smbpasswd -an noboday`. What is the `pdbedit`-pendant for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sudo pdbedit –a –u nobody

> -a|--create
>       This option is used to add a user into the database. This command needs a user name specified with the -u switch. When adding a new user, pdbedit will also ask for the password to be used.

```
Example: pdbedit -a -u sorce 

new password:
retype new password
```

[pdbedit(8) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pdbedit)